# How or When is time window of Kafka Streams expired?

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregate, apache-kafka-streams

I use kafka streams in my application, I have a question about time window in aggregate function.

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, PredictReq> windowedKtable = views.map(new ValueMapper()).groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)))
            .aggregate(new ADInitializer(), new ADAggregator(),Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), ReqJsonSerde));

KStream<Windowed<String>, Req> filtered = windowedKtable.toStream().transform(new ADTransformerFilter());

KStream<String, String> result = filtered.transform(new ADTransformerTrans());
```

I aggregrate data in 1 minute window and then transform to get the final aggregate result and do a second transform.

Here is some sample data:

msg1: 10:00:00 comes, msg2: 10:00:20 comes, msg3: 10:01:10  comes

window starts from 10:00:00 to 10:01:00 for example.

I found the windows is not expired until msg3 comes! (because the following transform is not executed until msg3 comes.)

This is not what I want.

Is there something wrong in my testing? If this is truth, how to change it?

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax Will you please answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see...

Kafka streams doesn't have the `window expired` concept. so I use window in message to check whether the window is changed, so I must wait message from next window.

If next message is not come, I don't know the window is finished.